# How to publish our Webservices

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have created an web service I need to publish this service. I need to host and authenticated users need to access my services using ASP.net 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are asking for an alternative, but I've been experimenting with [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/generic_wcf_host.aspx) that seems to work well on codeproject.com (CP).

If your question is on security, perhaps [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfcertificates.aspx) on CP is a useful start.